# Problem executing commands from the cdo (climate data operators) package in jupyter notebook / terminal

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cdo-climate, jupyter-console

My aim is to run a simple command from the cdo package (timmean) on a netcdf file. I have successfully installed the package but cannot seem to run commands.

***In jupyter terminal*** 
When I navigate to the relevant directory and run the command I receive the error:

```
"cdo : The term 'cdo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
+ cdo timmean infile.nc outfile.nc
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cdo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"
```

***In Jupyter Notebook***
As outlined in documentation I have tried first importing and initiating an object:

```
from cdo import *
cdo = Cdo()
```

But tracing back the issue to the second line of code I receive the error:
 `"FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"`

Any help appreciate, thanks.